# So I made a meme command for my discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    got('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/random/.json')
        .then(response => {
            const [list] = JSON.parse(response.body);
            const [post] = list.data.children;

            const permalink = post.data.permalink;
            const memeUrl = `https://reddit.com${permalink}`;
            const memeImage = post.data.url;
            const memeTitle = post.data.title;
            const memeUpvotes = post.data.ups;
            const memeNumComments = post.data.num_comments;

            embed.setTitle(`${memeTitle}`);
            embed.setURL(`${memeUrl}`);
            embed.setColor('BLACK');
            embed.setImage(memeImage);
            embed.setFooter(` ${memeUpvotes}  |   ${memeNumComments}`);

            message.channel.send(embed);
        })
```

Here's the code. What I want it to do is to only show memes with more than 4k upvotes, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

You may apply a really simple approach , add an if statement

```js
if(parseInt(post.data.ups) > 4000) {
// Code here 
}
```

`parseInt()` is a function that returns an integral value you can work with, rest seems self explanatory .

Comment: I tried it out, works like a charm. The only problem is that if it had gotten a meme with less than 4k upvotes before, it wont give any output. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Your questions states you need to show only upto 4k upvotes so I did that haha anyways you may add an `else` statement with it for less than 4k 
```if(parseInt(post.data.ups) > 4000) {
// Code here 
} else { 
// aww man less than 4k upvotes 
}```, make sure to mark it as correct for extra rep!

Comment: @AromaticArmadillo you can accept this answer by clicking the check mark if this helped you :D